# React-Bootstrap Tabs defaultActiveKey is not changing with stateChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, tabs, react-bootstrap

**`<Tabs>`** won't change **defaultActiveKey** with the State change.

1. I had to by Default Open "write" tab for one case scenario
2. And then by Default Open "read" tab for another case scenario

My code is like this

```
this.state = {
 defaultTab: "write"
}

functionToChangeDefaultTab()=>{
 this.setState({defaultTab: "read"})
}

render(){
 return(
   <Tabs defaultactivekey={this.state.defaultTab} transition={false} onSelect={this.onTabSelected}>
    <Tab eventKey="read" title="read"></Tab>
    <Tab eventKey="write" title="write"></Tab>
    .
    .
   </Tabs>


);
}
```

Even after running the Function to setState defaultTab to "read" value, "write" tab opens.
I don't know, how to put defaultActiveTab dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

why you are not using activeKey prop and passing your state

```
          <Tabs
          activeKey={activeTab}
          id="uncontrolled-tab-example"
          onSelect={(k) => {
            setactiveTab(k || '');
            nevagitation({
              search: `?tab=${k}`,
            });
          }}
          className="bluebordertabs"
        >
     //other code
        </Tabs>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

it seems your issues come from

- wrong props ❌**defaultactivekey** passed to Tabs component
  --> should be camelCase: ✅default**A**ctive**K**ey
- your function syntaxe depends on class based component.
  if it is the case, I reckon you wanted to do the following

```js
class NAMEOFYOURCOMPONENT extends React.Component {
 /* - This syntax ensures `this` is bound within functionToChangeDefaultTab.
    - Warning: this is *experimental* syntax.
     ( from react's doc see: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)
    - you wrote: ❌ functionToChangeDefaultTab()=>{ ... } */

     // ✅ should be
     functionToChangeDefaultTab = () => {
       // ... code ...
     }


     render() {
       return (
        {/* ... code ... */}
       );
     }
}
```

Then it should work.

Comment: Hey Lowla, I get your point. I think I tried Using the camelCase, "defaultActiveKey" It did't work.

Comment: @PanktiBardolia here is the implementation I did ( unfortunately with React Hooks not class based ) [codeSandbox-react-bootstrap-tabs](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-tabs-9m0bq?file=/src/components/TabsPanel/index.js)
If it can help you understand, I'll try to find more time for class based component later on